# balanced parenthesis using xor

Tags: java, string, ascii, bit, parentheses

I am trying to understand the following two snippets:

```
    String s = "abba";

    int xor = 0 ;
    char[] _s = s.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0;i<_s.length;i++){
        xor = xor^_s[i];
    }
    System.out.println(xor);
```

For the above code, the value of xor after for loop is 0. And I get that because of the property of XOR. However I am not understanding the output of following code

```
    String s = "{()}";

    int xor = 0 ;
    char[] _s = s.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0;i<_s.length;i++){
        xor = xor^_s[i];    
    }   
    System.out.println(xor);
```

The output of xor is 7. I would like to understand how? and why?. As per my understanding XOR operation, results 1 only for distinct values. i.e 0^1 = 1
and 1 ^ 1 or a ^ a = 0

Comment: Why shouldn't the answer be 7?

Comment: `a` and `a` are the same character and cancel out.  `{` and `}` are not the same character and don't cancel out.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case you have four different characters `{()}`. The value of xor is (by their ascii codes): `0x7b ^ 0x28 ^ 0x29 ^ 0x7d == 7`

Answer (score 0):

You're not feeding it 1s and 0s. You're feeding it character values.

It works for the  first case because the a's and b's cancel out.

It can't work for the second case.